# CMFCToolbar treat toolbar buttons as a group (Check/Uncheck)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, cmfctoolbar

I have three buttons in a `CMFCToolbar` that is contained in a `CDialogEx`, that I have set their styles to `TBBS_CHECKGROUP`

This allows each button to be toggled from checked to unchecked states, however I'd like to treat these three buttons as a group and **ONLY** allow one button to be **checked** at a time.

I cannot find any way to achieve this.

Only one of the buttons below should be checked at a time. How can I ensure that the other buttons automaticaly are unchecked?

[image]

In my code:

```
DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;
if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle,
dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG))
{
    dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);
}

CMFCToolBarInfo info;

m_ToolBar.SetSizes(CSize(32, 32), CSize(32, 32));
BOOL ret2 = m_ToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDR_TOOLBAR1_PNG); // << THIS WORKS

CMFCToolBarButton but1(0, 0, L"HELLO", TRUE, 0);
CMFCToolBarButton but2(1, 1, L"HELLO", TRUE, 0);
CMFCToolBarButton but3(2, 2, L"HELLO", TRUE, 0);

but1.SetStyle(but1.m_nStyle | TBBS_CHECKGROUP);
but2.SetStyle(but2.m_nStyle | TBBS_CHECKGROUP);
but3.SetStyle(but3.m_nStyle | TBBS_CHECKGROUP);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(but1, 0);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(but2, 0);
m_ToolBar.InsertButton(but3, 0);
m_ToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText(0, _T("By"));
m_ToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText(1, _T("Your"));
m_ToolBar.SetToolBarBtnText(2, _T("Command"));
m_ToolBar.InsertSeparator(2);

m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, 400, 36, 0, 0);
```

**UPDATE:**

I've been able to get a partial workaround by adding `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI_RANGE` and using the following code (Although this allows me to ensure the other buttons are always unchecked, I'm still unable to change the state of the current button being clicked to keep it **checked**:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnUpdateViewFilterData(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
    
        UINT nID;
        UINT info;
        int img;
        m_ToolBar.GetButtonInfo(i, nID, info,img);
        int check = 2;
    
        if (nID != pCmdUI->m_nID)
        {
            UINT newStyle = m_ToolBar.GetButtonStyle(i) & ~(TBBS_CHECKED | TBBS_INDETERMINATE);
            if (check == 1)
                newStyle |= TBBS_CHECKED;
            else if (check == 2)
                newStyle |= TBBS_INDETERMINATE;
            m_ToolBar.SetButtonStyle(i, newStyle | TBBS_CHECKBOX);
        }

        if (nID == pCmdUI->m_nID)
        {
            // If the button that is clicked keep it selected
            //pCmdUI->SetCheck(1) // << Does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have defined three separate (i.e. independent) groups of checkboxes. Add the `TBBS_CHECKBOX` style to all three buttons but only add `TBBS_CHECKGROUP` to the first.

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion but I still see the same behaviour

Comment: Hmm. How about using `TBBS_GROUP` instead of `TBBS_CHECKGROUP`? In a resource-script, groups of radio-buttons are specified with the first in each mutually-exclusive set having the `WS_GROUP` style.

Comment: Tried just `TBBS_GROUP` for the first button, but then that button isn't able to be checked.

Comment: Needs `TBBS_GROUP|TBBS_CHECKBOX`, probably.

Comment: `TBBS_CHECKGROUP` = `TBBS_GROUP|TBBS_CHECKBOX` , I tried tried both still same issue.

Comment: I see in the documentation that the update UI mechanism doesn't work for a dialog box-based application. This causes pCmdUI->SetCheck(TRUE); to not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after much trial and error and a lot of coffee I have now established why `CMFCToolbar` fails to work correctly when in a `CDialogEx`.

I had noticed that even though I had implemented `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` for each of the buttons, any attempt to use `pCmdUI->SetCheck()` or `pCmdUI->Enable()` would always just silently fail.

It turns out that for these commands to work correctly in a `CDialogEx` the important missing piece of the puzzle is to ensure you set `m_ToolBar.SetRouteCommandsViaFrame(FALSE);`

And then finally to ensure that the update command is called at the very beginning to set the initial check box states just add the following:

```
ON_MESSAGE_VOID(WM_KICKIDLE, OnKickIdle)

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnKickIdle()
{
    if (IsWindowVisible())
    {
        CFrameWnd* pParent = (CFrameWnd*)this;
        if (pParent)
            m_ToolBar.OnUpdateCmdUI(pParent, (BOOL)FALSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, I learned a long time ago that the `CDialog` does not natively support the menu updating framework and that I had to duplicate bits of the SDI / MDI framework boilerplate code.